# A program with strange output

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

This is the program I am confused about:

```java
public class Demo {
    
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        if(count < 3) {
            count++;
            main(null);
        }else {
            System.out.println("else");
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
else
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

I do not understand why else is printed first. Can you explain that please? Thanks

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger. Or even just with a pencil and paper.

Comment: or even just a piece of paper and a pen to write out what happens at each line, writing out any print statements off to the side of your lines.

Comment: `if(count<3)` prints nothing, so you don't see it execute.  (A debugger would show it though.)  So the first print statement is `else`.  THEN the code fails the `if` test and "falls through" and executes the `Hello World` at the end three times, because `main` was called three times.

Comment: Like Mike I am also a fan of hand execution.  A debugger will show you correctly what is happening and can check your hand execution, but if you can do it by hand without the computer you will learn much faster.

Comment: Yes.  Hand execution forces you to *think* about what happens more deeply.  With a debugger, you can single step through the execution without understanding why it happens.

Comment: you to read more about recursion method in java https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/recursion

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is shown first on console does not mean that it is executed first.

When your code start do the `if` statement, and recall `main()`. There is no prints until `else` statement is reached. That is when `main()` is recalled three times.

So, the execution has increased the variable and has raised the `else`.

Then, for every recursion, before the `else/if` another line is printed.

Is for that reason beacuse you have first the `else` and later 4 times `Hello World!`. One for each recursion.

Answer (score 0):

In short your code has a few reasons as to why this behaves the way it does:

```
static int count = 0;
```

Your use static on count which means everything references the same integer.

```
main(null);
```

You recursively call `main`, but the caller is waiting for the `main` to exit. Because of this, you increment `count` three times, print "else" and finally "Hello, World!" on the main functions which are now finishing their execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have used recursion, so the `Hello World` print only will be executed when recursion (and also `if/else` statement) ends.

That's why the first line printed is `else`.